# How about origin repo updates after local `git fetch & git rebase`?

Tags: git, github

I get a GitHub Workflow snapshot:

[image]

In there I have a question:

you know there use `git fetch & git rebase` for making local repo synchronization with origin, then we can commit and make pull request.

but however there may be this kind of situation, after `git fetch & git rebase` the origin repo update, when I commit and make pull request, the `$user/repo` is behind the origin repo.

if in this case, what will happen and how to make solution?

---

**EDIT-01**

And I have another question,
when step 6, whether is push the `branch: myfeature`?

and in `$user/repo` create PR to `original/repo`, is push the `$user/repo branch: myfeature`?
Whether should the `$user/repo master` rebase(or merge) the `$user/repo branch: myfeature` before create pull request to `original/repo`?

after the created PR, should I delete the `$user/repo branch:myfeature` and `local/repo branch:myfeature`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step 4 (fetch+rebase) is done precisely for the `$user/repo` to *not* be behind the upstream repo (the original repository forked)

Your PR branch will be based on the latest from that original repository, and can be pushed to your fork to initiate a PR.

If that PR branch is behind the original repository, you repeat step 4: fetch (of upstream) + rebase (or your PR branch on top of `upstream/main`), plus a `git push --force`: your PR will be updated, and can be merged without conflict, since any conflict will have been resolved locally during the rebase.

Step 6 is `git push -u origin my_feature`, and indeed, that feature branch shoul d always be rebased first on top of `upstream/main` (or "`original/main`") before doing a PR, in order for that PR to be easily merged by the original repository maintainer.

> after the created PR, should I delete the $user/repo branch:myfeature and local/repo branch:myfeature?

Not right away: wait for the PR to be accepted first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have question about the workflow. how can `$user/repo master`  sync with `original/repo master`.

Comment: @user7693832 it syncs through your local clone: you fetch from one (original) to push to the other ($user)

Comment: but in there I only push the `brach: myfeature`,  you mean I should push `local/repo master` too?

Comment: @user7693832 You don't need to sync/push master. You don't work on master, only feature. As long as feature is rebased on top of original/master, you are good to go.